PySpark application connection to Azure SQL (Service Principal Based Auth)
I want to connect to Azure SQL which has Service Principal based authentication enabled. I want specifically pyODBC to connect to the DB. I am writing the following code:
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Azure SQL Active Directory Service Principal Connection") \
    .getOrCreate()


resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"
client_id = "xxx-xxxxx"
client_secret = "xxx~Sxxxx"
tenant_id = "xxx-xxxxx"
database_server = "xxx-xxxx.database.windows.net;PORT=xxxx;"
database_name = "xxxx-xxxx-dev"
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id

database_server2="xxxx-xxxx.database.windows.net"


app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Scope for Azure SQL Database
scope = ["https://database.windows.net//.default"]

# Get the token
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
print("Token:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
print(token_response)


if "access_token" not in token_response:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to acquire token: {token_response.get('error_description')}")

access_token = token_response["access_token"]

# Use PyODBC to connect to the database
connection_string = (
    "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    f"SERVER={database_server2};"
    f"DATABASE={database_name};"
)

exptoken = b''
tokenb = bytes(access_token, "UTF-8")
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken



# PyODBC requires the token to be passed separately
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before={1256: tokenstruct}) #access_token

# Test the connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
print("Printing Event Rows:::")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM xx.xx")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)

# Close the connection
connection.close()

Now this code is working fine. But it doesn't work if I remove this part of the code that manipulates the token.
exptoken = b''
tokenb = bytes(access_token, "UTF-8")
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

If I use the access_token directly like this way:
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before={1256: access_token})

the connection never get established.
Is there any way to avoid token manipulation? Or is it mandatory? I've followed this doc which connects through ADAL https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-azure-ad-service-principals-connect-sql-from-python-andrade/

Are you getting any error? and do you want to use Adal package to connect SQL db?

Actually in adal I had to twitch the token. So thought if I use msal I don't have to...but it seems both the cases I have to modify the toke which I'm trying to avoid.

Hi @PAMPA ROY, can you check the below provided answer, let me know is it helpful or not?


Is there any way to avoid token manipulation? Or is it mandatory?

If you won't manipulate the token, then you will get below error:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect);

Even though the access token acquired is correct, you will get login failed error, the reason for this is Python doesn't recognize some SQL types that we need to use before opening a connection using attributes. So first we need to define what the token means. SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN is 1256; it's specific to msodbcsql driver so pyodbc does not have it defined, and likely will not. Then we need to translate the token to a data format that SQL understands.
To give an end-to-end description, if the JSON response containing the token from the OAuth server looks like the bytes "eyJ0eXAiOi..." (in hex 65 79 4A 30 65 58 41 69 4F 69...) then the structure passed to the driver needs to have a 0 byte inserted after every token byte, e.g. 65 00 79 00 4A 00 30 00 65 00 58 00 41 00 69 00 4F 00 69 00. So, Manipulating the token is mandatory while using access-based authentication. Then you will be able to connect the Azure SQL database with provided successfully as shown below:
Code:
import pyodbc
import struct
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"
client_id = '<clientId>'
tenant_id = '<tenantId>'
client_secret = '<clientSecret>'
database_server = "<servereName>.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;"
database_name = "<dbName>"
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id



app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

# Scope for Azure SQL Database
scope = ["https://database.windows.net//.default"]

# Get the token
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
print("Token:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
print(token_response)

if "access_token" not in token_response:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to acquire token: {token_response.get('error_description')}")

access_token = token_response["access_token"]

# Use PyODBC to connect to the database
connection_string = (
    "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    f"SERVER={database_server};"
    f"DATABASE={database_name};"
)
exptoken = b''
tokenb = bytes(access_token, "UTF-8")
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i})
    exptoken += bytes(1)
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken

# PyODBC requires the token to be passed separately
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, attrs_before={1256: tokenstruct}) #access_token

# Test the connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
print("Printing Event Rows:::")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Logs")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)


For more information you can refer to below documents:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-azure-ad-service-principals-connect-sql-from-python-andrade/

Connect Azure SQL Server using Service Principal


